# Balancer nginx based on value header

Tags: nginx, header, openresty

I am new to nginx, I want to ask for advice. I need to write the following logic for a balancer. Requests go to the public address gate.mysite.com and are then proxied to one of the four external servers remote[1-4].server.com.
If the request contains a header "X-Stamp" with some number, then the requests are routed to the server, the number of which is calculated using the formula (X-Stamp mod 4)+1. If there is no header "X-Stamp" then Round Robin. Also, there are the following routing rules:

```
gate1.mysite.com -> remote1.server.com
gate2.mysite.com -> remote2.server.com
gate3.mysite.com -> remote3.server.com
gate4.mysite.com -> remote4.server.com
```

I wrote such a config using nginx openresty.

```
http {
upstream host1 {
        server remote1.server.com:443;
}
upstream host2 {
        server remote2.server.com:443;
}
upstream host3 {
        server remote3.server.com:443;
}
upstream host4 {
        server remote4.server.com:443;
}
upstream all {
        server remote1.server.com:443;
        server remote2.server.com:443;
        server remote3.server.com:443;
        server remote4.server.com:443;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        server_name gate.mysite.com;
        ...
        location / {
                set $num_header_glob '';
                rewrite_by_lua_block {
                        --reading request headers
                        local req_headers = ngx.req.get_headers()
                        local num_header  = ""
                        -- checking an a header value to determine target uri
                        if req_headers["X-Stamp"] then
                                num_header = ((req_headers["X-Stamp"])%4)+1
                        else
                                -- default path if not header found
                                num_header = "5"
                        end
                        ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, string.format("resolved num_header: %s", num_header))
                        ngx.var.num_header_glob = num_header
                }
            proxy_pass https://$target_uri;
        }
        
}
map $num_header_glob $target_uri {
                "1" "host1";
                "2" "host2";
                "3" "host3";
                "4" "host4";
                "5" "all";
                }

}
server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        server_name gate1.mysite.com;
        ...
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://host1;
        }
}
server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        server_name gate2.mysite.com;
        ...
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://host2;
        }
}
server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        server_name gate3.mysite.com;
        ...
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://host3;
        }
}
server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        server_name gate4.mysite.com;
        ...
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://host4;
        }
}
}
```

But I need to supplement it with the following condition - if I received an HTTP-status 307 in the response, I need to replace the HTTP header Location value transmitted to the client

```
"remote1.server.com" to "gate1.mysite.com"
"remote2.server.com" to "gate2.mysite.com"
"remote3.server.com" to "gate3.mysite.com"
"remote4.server.com" to "gate4.mysite.com"
```

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [`header_filter`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#header_filter_by_lua) phase. Something like:

```
header_filter_by_lua_block {
  if ngx.status == 307 then
    ngx.header["Location"] = (ngx.header["Location"] or ""):gsub("://remote(%d).server.com", "://gate%1.mysite.com")
  end
}
```